# Taylor's Polynomial with Lagrange's form of remainder.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose our function be written as 
$$f(x)=P_n(x)+R_n(x)$$ where $P_n(x)$ is n-th Taylor's Polynomial about $x_0$ and $R_n(x)$ is associated remainder/error term both of which are given as 
$$P_n(x)= \sum _ { k = 0 } ^ { n } \frac { f ^ { ( k ) } \left( x _ { 0 } \right) } { k ! } \left( x - x _ { 0 } \right) ^ { k }$$
$$R _ { n } ( x ) = \frac { f ^ { ( n + 1 ) } ( \xi ( x ) ) } { ( n + 1 ) ! } \left( x - x _ { 0 } \right) ^ { n + 1 }\quad \text{for }  \xi(x)\in [x,x_0]$$

Suppose $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}R_n(x)=0$ or in other words  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P_n(x)=f(x)$

Define  $$g(n)=\sup |R_n(x)| = \sup |f(x)-P_n(x)|$$

Can it be proven that $g(n)=\sup |R_n(x)|$ is decreasing function of $n$

Comment: For one $x$ or every $x?$ What are you taking the $\sup$ over? Where is $f$ defined?

Comment: @zhw. For any general function. We are talking for all those x at which  taylor's polynomial converges to the function.

Comment: Let $f(x)= e^x.$ Then $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |e^x-P_n(x)| = \infty$ for any $n.$

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$ on $[-2,0]$. Expand it at $x =0$, then
$$
f^{(n)}(0) = n!(1-x)^{-(n+1)}|_{x=0} = n!, 
$$
and the Taylor formula is
$$
f(x) = \sum_0^n x^j + (1- \xi)^{-(n+2)} x^{n+1}. 
$$
Now
$$
\sup |R_n(x)| = \sup\left| \frac 1{1-x}- \sum_0^n x^j\right| = \sup\left|\frac {1-(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x}\right| = \sup \left|\frac{x^{n+1}} {1-x}\right| =\sup \frac {(-x)^{n+1}} {1-x} \geqslant \frac {2^{n+1}} {1+2} \nearrow +\infty, 
$$
so the sequence $g(n)$ cannot be decreasing.

#### UPDATE

Inspired by @zhw., if the interval is $(-1,1)$ instead, then
$$
g(n) \geqslant \frac {(1-1/n)^{n+1}}{1 - 1+1/n} \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} +\infty,
$$
and $g(n)$ still cannot be decreasing.

Comment: Can we claim that $g(n)$ will be decreasing with $n$ only for those functions whose Taylor's polynomial will converge to the function.

Comment: On $[-2,0]?$ i would think the natural domain here is $(-1,1).$ Why did you take the absolute values off at the end there? Actually the $\sup = \infty$ for every $n.$

Comment: That is before the OP added the restriction $R_n(x)\to 0$.